# Mysql PreparedStatement Query returns 0 rows though table has newly inserted data

Tags: java, sql, mysql, prepared-statement, vert.x

I'm porting an old java program that polls the db every few minutes. It simply queries a certain table and based on the row values processes them (i have to maintain the polling, can't change to CDC like debezium). I am using vertx `setTimer` to do the periodic scheduling (so that one starts after the previous has ended). I have this property in the class `private static Handler<Long> pollingHandler;` and initialize it as below and call it for the first time. When I copy the query `FETCH_SAMPLE_DATA_QUERY` with various valid parameters of `start_id` and `batch_size` and use it in mysql console, it works. In code, **only the first call** works and returns the right number of rows, and after finished processing `start_id` is updated for the next scheduled call. But the subsequent scheduled calls all return 0 rows. The logs are filled with `Processing 0 records` when I debug. I can't seem to understand why it's returning an empty RowSet. The initial call does update `start_id` when I check the debug logs and therefore second call should return new batch of rows but it returns empty and so goes for the rest of the subsequent calls. The debug value for `start_id` remains the same after it was updated by the first call. When I replace `?` in the query with the debug values and run the query in mysql console, it returns `batch_size` number of rows. I can't seem to understand how this is happening.

```
  pollingHandler = id -> {
   LOGGER.debug("start_id: {}", start_id);
   LOGGER.debug("batch_size: {}", batch_size);

   mysqlClient
    .preparedQuery(FETCH_SAMPLE_DATA_QUERY)
    .execute(Tuple.of(start_id,batch_size))
    .onSuccess(rows -> {
      LOGGER.debug("Processing {} rows", rows.size());
      
      if (rows.size() > 0) {
        RowIterator<Row> rowIterator = rows.iterator();
        processRows(rowIterator); // this updates start_id so that the next query starts from somewhere else
      }
      vertx.setTimer(config.getLong("polling-interval"), pollingHandler);
    })
    .onFailure(err -> {
      LOGGER.error(err.getMessage(),err);
      vertx.setTimer(config.getLong("polling-interval"), pollingHandler);
    });
 };

 // Schedule the first execution
 vertx.setTimer(config.getInteger("polling-interval"), pollingHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the above prepared statement query runs perfectly fine against `mariadb 10.5` but fails against `MySQL 8.0.25` even though `max_prepared_stmt_count` is set to non-zero value. I changed the code from using `preparedQuery` with `connectOptions.setCachePreparedStatements(true)` to simply using `query` with concatenated parameters and it started working. Not sure if it is a bug or not.